# ¿Cómo obtengo el valor del input (radiobutton) seleccionado con Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

¿Cómo puedo obtener el `value` del `input` que seleccione y al clickar en `buy now` el mismo valor se muestre en el `div` llamado `#purchase` en **jQuery**?

```js
edition[2] = $('#gold');
edition[3] = $('#diamond');
edition[4] = $('#platinum');

$default = $('#default');
$input = $('input.formulari');

$default.prop("checked", true);

$(":checked").wrap("<div style='background-color:black'></div>");

$input.on('change', function() {
  $input.not(this).prop('checked', false);
});

$("#purchase").hide();
$("#buy").click(function() {

  $("#main").fadeOut("fast", function() {

    $("#purchase").fadeIn();
  });

  $('#purchase').html();

  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="main">
  <form id="testForm" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="box">
      <input type="radio" id="default" class="formulari" name="radioName">
      <p class="order" id="standard">STANDARD EDITION</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <input type="radio" class="formulari" name="radioName" value="silveredition">
      <p class="order" id="silver">SILVER EDITION</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <input type="radio" class="formulari" name="radioName">
      <p class="order" id="gold">GOLD EDITION</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <input type="radio" class="formulari" name="radioName">
      <p class="order" id="diamond">DIAMOND EDITION</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <input type="radio" class="formulari" name="radioName">
      <p class="order" id="platinum">PLATINUM EDITION</p>
    </div>
  </form>
  <div id="buy"> <a href="">BUY NOW</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="purchase">
  <p id="thanks">THANK YOU!</p>
  <div id="label"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Por favor traduce tu pregunta al **Español**, recuerda que estas en **StackOverflow en Español**. Ademas trata de ser mas especifco con tu pregunta. Especifica que error tienes.

Comment: Ya esta, Gracias @IvanBotero

Comment: Sin animo de ser alguien molesto, yo te recomendaria que en el titulo, expusieras la idea general de tu pregunta, e.g: _Manejo de elementos en jQuery_, _Cambiar un elemento via jQuery_ y en el cuerpo de la pregunta especifique ya el problema.

Comment: necesito obtener el "value" del input que seleccione y al clickar en "buy now" el mismo valor se muestre en div con id #purchase Jquery?
Gracias @IvanBotero soy nuevo aquí

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tu función debería quedar así para obtener el valor del radio seleccionado.

```
    $("#buy").click(function() {
       alert($('input[name=radioName]:checked', '#testForm').val());
    });
```

Y todos tus campos `radio` deberian tener un atributo `value`.

```
<input type="radio" class="rad" name="radioName" value="VALOR">
```

Comment: Genial, funciona. MUY agradecido :)